# Why Select eliminating NULL records on a varchar comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 782,856 records. There is a column PEOPLE_TYPE in this table that is varchar(20). I don't think table schema matters but if it does I will gladly post it.

It has these distinct values (parens is a count of each type):

```
NULL (782,101)
ANONYMOUS (1)
BOARD (530)
USER (224)
```

So why does this select return these results???

```
select * from people where PEOPLE_TYPE != 'BOARD'
```

This return 225 rows...USER & ANONYMOUS....why aren't my nulls included...because I have now performed a text search and NULLs can't really be compared so they are eliminated?

Thank You for your patience with my remedial question.

Comment: NULL is UNKNOWN. Now how can you compare two things when you don't even know what they are ? Now, think about all things you were comparing with NULL. The results will make sense to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NULL is a strange thing. Any comparison with NULL is false:

NULL = NULL is false

NULL != anything is false

NULL != NULL is also false.

You have to say things like column is null, or column is not null.

Your query would need

```
select * from people where PEOPLE_TYPE != 'BOARD' or PEOPLE_TYPE is null
```

Comment: Or, my favourite, `where IsNull(PEOPLE_TYPE, '') != 'BOARD'`

Comment: Indeed - I didn't mention it as isnull is SQL Server and I wanted to make it a general answer. Cheers -

Comment: Not to labour it too much, but the question is tagged sql-server, only mysql does not do a good IsNull, and you should point out that parenthesis are needed around your version if used with any other where conditions because of the 'or'.

Comment: OK, thanks. The last I looked Oracle didn't have one though that was v8 so a long time ago. As for parens, in the query I put up they're not needed. If other where clauses are used then they probably would be.

Comment: @rolfl . . . I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean, but the ANSI standard is `coalesce()`, not `isnull()`, and `coalesce()` is supported by all serious databases.

Comment: Comparisons against NULL in SQL are neither true nor false; the result is UNKNOWN.  You gotta love three-way Boolean logic :)

Comment: Sort of, yes. But is a precitical implementation it will evaluate to either true or false. Forex. this query returns 3 zeroes: select case when 1 = null then 1 else 0 end, case when null <> null then 1 else 0 end, case when 1 <> null then 1 else 0 end

Comment: I should never have suggested more than my initial comment about the IsNull being shorter/simpler than the full 'or'. Point taken. IsNull is not as widely supported as I thought, at least, not with that name. Use Coalesce and move on.

Comment: simon at rcl, how about: select case when 1 = null then 'true' else CASE WHEN 1 <> null then 'false' ELSE 'unknown' END END

Comment: Sure. But being put into a 2 valued function and behaving as I'd expect in always taking the False option I'd argue that although theoretically you're entirely right, practically it makes no difference. I wouldn't want to get into an argument about it, though, because you are correct!

Comment: I wasn't trying to be pedantic.  I just wanted to make sure that user1278561 understands that 3-way logic is involved.  The concept of `UNKNOWN` rather than just true/false is even more of a gotcha when dealing with set-based expressions involving NULL values, such as a `NOT IN` subquery that includes a NULL value.

Comment: It is an important distinction. If it was false then you could make it true by putting `NOT` in front of it. But `NOT (NULL = NULL)` doesn't evaluate to true either.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this for details on why records with NULL are not being returned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

If you want records with NULL to be returned you need to write the query like this:

```
select * from people where ISNULL(PEOPLE_TYPE, '0') != 'BOARD'
```

Or this:

```
select * from people where PEOPLE_TYPE != 'BOARD' OR PEOPLE_TYPE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another thing called COALESCE, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx
I use quite often,

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE COALESCE(PEOPLE_TYPE, '') != 'BOARD'
```